Why does typescript not allow to partially specify type arguments in order to create a new generic function from another generic function?
I'm learning about generic in typescript, specifically Instantiation Expressions.
I wonder that: Why typescript does not allow to partially specify type arguments in generic function in order to create a new generic function which has less type variables (the new generic function is less flexible and reusable in terms of type than the old one).
For example:
type TypeA = { a: string };         // line (1)

function mergeFunc<T_1, T_2>(a: T_1, b: T_2) {      // line (2)
    return { ...a, ...b };                          // line (3)
}

let newGenMergeFunc = mergeFunc<TypeA, Tp>;         // line (4)

In the example, I have one type definetion (typeA) and mergeFunc function which contain 2 type variables (T_1 and T_2). Type signature of mergeFunc is:
mergeFunc<T_1, T_2>(a: T_1, b: T_2): T_1 & T_2 
I want to create a more specific version of mergeFunc using instantiation expression. I have created a new function (newGenMergeFunc) by passing actual type TypeA to the first type parameter (T_1) and keeping the second type parameter being as a type variable (Tp).
When I run the example above, I expect that: newGenMergeFunc will become a generic function having one type variable (Tp) and its signature is :
newGenMergeFunc<Tp>(a: TypeA, b: Tp): TypeA & T_2. In that, TypeA is the actual type while Tp is a type parameter ( type placeholder or type variable).  However, Typescript compiler does not permit me to do that.
Could you give the reason? Thanks for considering my stupid question.

The reason is that it's a missing feature. TS doesn't let you skip generics when you call a generic function as per ms/TS#10571 and there's also no corresponding way to do so with an instantiation expression. If you want this behavior you have to write the type out manually, as shown in Caleth's answer below.

You can, but the syntax you used is incorrect.
let newGenMergeFunc:<Tp> (a: TypeA, b: Tp) => TypeA & Tp = mergeFunc;

You need to have a context where Tp is already a type parameter for mergeFunc<TypeA, Tp> to be valid, e.g.
function makeMergeFunc<Tp>(){ return mergeFunc<TypeA, Tp>; }
let unknownMergeFunc = makeMergeFunc();

Playground link

thank you @Caleth, Your answer make me so interesting. But in your answer let newGenMergeFunc:<Tp> (a: TypeA, b: Tp) => TypeA & Tp = mergeFunc; use the Contextual Typing and not use  Instantiation Expressions.

@LeoPkm2-1 see edit. You need a place for Tp to be introduced as a type parameter

Thank you so much, after considering your answer carefully, I have understood. Sorry for this late response. My sincerest thanks
